# HP SmartArray P212 disabled, cache module not attached

Tags: linux, raid, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I have a DL180 G6 server with Smart Array P212 RAID controller. The server runs under Ubuntu. After an upgrade from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 utility `hpacucli` (ver. 8.50-6.0) stopped working. The error message was about missing controller. I updated the utility to version 9.10.22.0. Now, the message is:

```
Smart Array P212 in Slot 1

CACHE STATUS PROBLEM DETECTED: The controller is disabled because the cache
                           module is not attached. Please re-attach the
                           cache module to re-enable the controller.
```

But all disks are available, even though the I/O speed makes me nervous. Is this for real, should I start investigating a problem with the cache module? Or is this a compatibility problem between Ubuntu 12.04 and `hpacucli`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the firmware on the Smart Array P212 device as a good measure... The [current version is 6.00](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=329290&prodSeriesId=3885791&prodNameId=3885792&swEnvOID=4103&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-2de8d504c7d14295988a808327).

The real issue is that the hpacucli utility needs to be downgraded. Can you try an older version?

The best place to look is the HP SDR repository:
http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/downloads/ProLiantSupportPack/Ubuntu/dists/

Comment: I have already tested versions 8.28, 8.35, 8.60 and 8.70 :). All they return is:
    Error: No controllers detected. BTW, I have another server with Ubuntu 12.04, where hpacucli 9.10 works correctly. The controller, though, is different, P222.

Comment: Update your controller's firmware.

Comment: I will, as soon as I have a chance to shut down the server. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the controller firmware (two reboots were necessary). Downgrade didn't work, older versions of `hpacucli` still do not find the controller, but 9.10 works correctly now. Thanks!